# Remove words with capital letters

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I am trying to write a regular expression for this list:

```
data = ["Canada is developing country. Fred works as Deputy Manager in Canada.", "Rishi is working for Fred in the same company.", "Rita is another employee in AC Corp."]
```

And I want to delete all the words that starts with an uppercase letter but it should not check the first word of every sentence ** if it has not been anywhere in the whole data list in middle of any sentence ie, it should not check for Rishi , Rita while Canada  and Fred should be removed since they have occurred later in the middle of the sentence.
Appreciated if there is any other faster solution other than regular expressions.

The output should be:

```
["is developing country.works as in.", "Rishi is working for in the same company.", "Rita is another employee in."]
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Firs you could split each string on ".". Then you could put each string in different lists. Next, you could split each string on " ". Finnaly, you could start checking for capital letters starting from the 1 element of each list instead of 0. Done! :)