# Remove Greek words with capital letters

Tags: python, regex

I want to delete Greek words with capital letters, such as:

```
text = 'Ο Κώστας θέλει να ΠΑΙΞΕΙ ΑΎΡΙΟ ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο'
```

The output should be:

```
text = 'Ο Κώστας θέλει να ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο'
```

I checked this one [Regular expression : Remove words with Capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603403/regular-expression-remove-words-with-capital-letters), but I don't know how to adapt the code to the Greek alphabet.

Comment: What is *your* code? What is the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The Java answer you'd linked did not work for Python (I tried), hence the reopen.

Comment: @AKX What did not work? That just means you did not try well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can (by consulting an Unicode chart) see that the Greek letters are approximately in the range U+0370..U+1FFF, and then filter using the `unicodedata` module:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> greek_capital_chars = set(chr(cp) for cp in range(0x0370, 0x1FFF) if "GREEK CAPITAL" in unicodedata.name(chr(cp), ""))
{'Β', 'Χ', 'ᾛ', 'Ἁ', 'Ὼ', 'ᾜ', 'ᾫ', 'Ἂ', 'Ὰ', 'Ἑ', 'Ω', 'Ἤ', 'Ε', 'Ρ', 'Η', 'ᾏ', 'Ϳ', 'Ή', 'Ἣ', 'Ἵ', 'ᾋ', 'Ύ', 'ᾚ', 'Ή', 'Ϲ', 'Ί', 'Ὥ', 'Ύ', 'Ξ', 'Ὄ', 'Ο', 'Θ', 'Ϗ', 'Ϋ', 'Ͻ', 'ᾘ', 'Ὑ', 'Ώ', 'Ᾰ', 'ᾝ', 'Ἐ', 'Ὦ', 'Ά', 'Σ', 'Ὂ', 'Ἱ', 'Ὤ', 'Ͷ', 'Ὴ', 'Ό', 'Ψ', 'ῼ', 'Φ', 'Ἒ', 'Ὕ', 'ᾪ', 'Ἅ', 'Ῑ', 'Ἧ', 'Λ', 'Ἢ', 'Ϸ', 'Ἔ', 'Ί', 'Ἇ', 'Ἲ', 'Ὓ', 'Ζ', 'Τ', 'Ὗ', 'Ϊ', 'Ͽ', 'Μ', 'Ὀ', 'Ἄ', 'ᾊ', 'Κ', 'Γ', 'Ὶ', 'Ϻ', 'Ᾱ', 'ᾬ', 'Ώ', 'Ἳ', 'Ἥ', 'Ἦ', 'Ι', 'Ἃ', 'ᾌ', 'Ὁ', 'Έ', 'Δ', 'Ὡ', 'Ἆ', 'Ἰ', 'ϴ', 'Ͼ', 'Ῠ', 'ῌ', 'Ἓ', 'Ἕ', 'Έ', 'Ὃ', 'Ὠ', 'ᾈ', 'Ͱ', 'ᾼ', 'Ὢ', 'ᾙ', 'ᾞ', 'ᾎ', 'Ὸ', 'Ῥ', 'Ἀ', 'Ὣ', 'Ͳ', 'Ἶ', 'Ῐ', 'ᾮ', 'ᾍ', 'Ἡ', 'Ῡ', 'Ὧ', 'ᾉ', 'ᾩ', 'ᾯ', 'ᾭ', 'ᾟ', 'Ό', 'Α', 'Ὲ', 'Υ', 'Π', 'Ἴ', 'Ά', 'Ἷ', 'ᾨ', 'Ὅ', 'Ὺ', 'Ν', 'Ἠ'}
```

Then, you can form a regexp that matches words (continous runs) of such characters. We'll also include Latin capital characters.

```
>>> import re
>>> import string
>>> chars_class = re.escape("".join(greek_capital_chars.union(string.ascii_uppercase)))
>>> r = re.compile(f"[{chars_class}]+")
>>> text = 'Ο Κώστας θέλει να ΠΑΙΞΕΙ ΑΎΡΙΟ ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο'
>>> r.sub("", text)
' ώστας θέλει να   ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο'
```

As it is, the regex will of course also remove any capital letter; you may wish to do

```
>>> r = re.compile(f"[{chars_class}]{{2,}}")
>>> r.sub("", text)
'Ο Κώστας θέλει να   ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο'
```

or similar instead, depending on your use case.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable help! This is exactly what I was looking for! By using {{2,}} means a word with more than 2 letters, right?

Comment: @George Yes, two or more consecutive letters. You could also try the `\b` and `\s` anchors to have the regexp work with word boundaries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there any way to adopt your code into the case that we should be removing any chunk of text and spaces that starts with capitals and contains only capitals?

Comment: `f"[{chars_class}][{chars_class} ]+"`?

Comment: I was thinking the same but for this input = 'Ο ΚΩΣΤΑΣ ΘΕΛΕΙ. να ΠΑΙΞΕΙ ΑΎΡΙΟ ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο', the output is '. να ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο', but I want this ouput = 'να ΠΑΙΞΕΙ ΑΎΡΙΟ ποδόσφαιρο στο σχολείο'.